# Variable to check if viewing an entry?

Tags: variable

How would I write a variable to detect if the current page/Url I'm viewing is for an entry, rather than a section home page or a single?

i.e

```
{% if I'm currently viewing an entry %}
    do this
{% else %}
    do this
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three [types of sections](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types) in Craft: singles, structures, and channels. You can use `entry.section.type` to test if the current page is displaying one of these section types.

```
{% if entry.section.type == "channel" %}

    <p>This is a channel</p>

{% elseif entry.section.type == "single" %}

    <p>This is a single</p>

 {% elseif entry.section.type == "structure" %}

    <p>This is a structure</p>

 {% endif %}
```